# How to convert audio stream from PureTool/CVS video?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, quicktime

I apologize if there is a better place to post this.  I recently came across a couple CVS single-use video cameras that I had been using back in 2005.  I still have the USB cable I made and now that I've switched to Mac I can use [Puretool](http://www.koiproductions.com/PureTool/) to extract the old videos from the cameras.  The problem I'm having is that I can only hear the audio when viewing the videos with VLC media player.  I read on PureTools site, a common problem is that the audio codec used is incompatible with Quicktime and the audio stream needs to be converted.  There is a link on their site to a program called FixSound which is purported to fix this, but the link is dead and I've been unable to find any further information about this.  If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful.  All the videos I'm dealing with are from the first year of my son's life and I'd really like to be able to archive them in a more uniform format.  I would think this would be possible to do using Adobe Audition or some other program in Adobe's CS6 Master Collection but I've only dealt with Photoshop, Illustrator, Dreamweaver, Flash & Fireworks.  I have no experience with audio or video yet.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround but if anyone has a better suggestion, please post.

I used SoundConverter / GStreamer on my Ubuntu box to convert the audio from the old video to mp3 then combined that with the original video on my iMac using Encore and built it as .f4v (for achiving, I can just build a DVD from Encore). I guess from there I can use Media Encoder to come up with a Quicktime, 3gp, etc... version.